# What is a class of a graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I found this question on my textbook.What is the class of the graphs in which every Eulerian cycle is also a Hamiltonian cycle, but I don't understand what he means by class.

Comment: It means, for which graphs is every Eulerian Cycle a hamiltonian cycle?

Answer (score 4):

There is a family of graphs $G$ with the property that every Eulerian cycle in $G$ is also a Hamiltonian cycle. It turns out that these graphs can be described in a simple way that does not mention Eulerian or Hamiltonian cycles at all. You’re being asked to find such a description. For example, if it turned out that a graph $G$ had this property if and only if $G$ was complete, you could answer the question by saying that it’s the class of complete graphs. (It isn’t, however.)

HINT: Start by showing that if $G$ is a graph with this property, then the number of edges in $G$ must be the same as the number of vertices.

**Added:** If the wording of the problem is taken literally, every graph that has no Eulerian cycle vacuously has the stated property. I suspect that the author did not consider this possibility. If it *is* considered, we have to take the union of the class hinted at above and the class of graphs having no Eulerian cycle. The latter is easily described: it’s the class of all graphs that either are not connected or have a vertex of odd degree.

Comment: So the class of the graphs is a cycle?

Comment: @Mitsos: You have the right idea: the class in question is the class of all [cycle graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I have a question about this, wouldn't the graphs without eulerian cycles also qualify?

Comment: @dREaM: Yes, properly speaking, though I suspect that this was not intended. If it was, we’d have the class of graphs that are cycles, or are not connected, or have a vertex of odd degree. I suppose that I should add something to that effect.